# Strange Segmentation fault of function strcpy in linux c program

Tags: c, linux, gdb

Here is my source code:

```
char *
cpy_strcpy (dest, src)
     char *dest;
     const char *src;
{
  char c;
  char *s = (char *) src;
  const ptrdiff_t off = dest - s - 1;

  do
    {
       //c = *s++
       //s[off] = c;
       s[off] = *s;
    }
  while (*s++ != '\0');
  //while( c != '\0' );
  return dest;
}
```

I got this when i using gdb debug it:

```
(gdb) s
26    while (*s++ != '\0');
(gdb) 
27    return dest;
(gdb) 
28  }
(gdb) 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040050a in cpy_strcpy (dest=can't compute CFA for this frame
) at strcpy.c:28
28  }
```

This source code was copied from glibc but i changed some line(with comment //)

I really can't figure out what is wrong with my new code. anyone can help me?

### Thanks in advance!

Comment: @YuHao Here you comes! i also want to ask this question, this is my first time see K&R style as you call it, and anything different?

Comment: Where did you pick up that source from, can you provide a link? As far as I can tell it invokes undefined behavior in modern standards but seeing it is using K&R who knows how long ago it was written.

Comment: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/libc/ oh,god, i downloaded the 2.19 from this place. By the way, is K&R style out of style

Comment: Are you sure it is not crashing with unmodified version as well ? How do you call the function ?

Comment: @EricFortin pretty sure, it work well when i had not edit it!

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour hello?

Comment: To make that change, you also  need to ditch the -1 in the definition of off.

Comment: @RedWolf'sHusband sorry, I was thinking, about the undefined behavior. As far as I know no one doing modern develop uses K&R it is painful and really only useful for historical perspective. I still think in this is undefined behavior but since this is a core library they can decide to make it well defined but it would not be okay for user code to do so.

Comment: @rici any comments on the UB aspect of this code?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Sure, it's UB to do pointer arithmetic with pointers from different objects. But the standard library is allowed to break the rules (or be written in a different language). Indeed, there are parts of the standard library which are not implementable without some kind of UB (longjmp springs to mind). *Cargo culting* code from the standard library is therefore questionable, and clearly non-portable. I wouldn't recommend it, and I certainly wouldn't recommend modifying it because it is likely already subtly optimized. But trying to understand it can be fun, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`s[off] = *s` is wrong in the first loop.

`s[off]` points the address `s + off`, which in the first loop is:

```
s + off = s + (dest - s - 1) = dest - 1
```

The address `(dest - 1)` is out of the left bound of char array.

The original code is right, because `c = *s++` can firstly assign c with s, then increase s, which makes `s[off]` in `s[off] = c` just points to `dest`, not `dest - 1`.

Comment: You are right!But why Seg fail cause at the end of this function? the point shoud point at the end - 1 of dest. Am i right?

Comment: Writing to dest-1 messes up the return address pushed on the stack.

Comment: As @EricFortin said, segmentation fault can expose after the real error point, especially in multi-threading enviroment.